# Issues with query in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am tryig to get Minimum dates for each id, but's not giving me results.
Plz see sample data and queries I tried.

On Oracle: 11G

Table:

```
create table gr(id number, dept number, sal number, dates date);
```

Sample Data:

```
Id  DEPT    Sal     Dates   
1   10      5000    02-MAR-2018 16:34:46
1   10      2000    04-MAR-2018 16:34:46
1   10      1000    05-MAR-2018 16:34:46
1   10      (null)  06-MAR-2018 16:34:46
2   20      2000    07-MAR-2018 16:34:46
2   20      5000    08-MAR-2018 16:34:46
2   20      (null)  09-MAR-2018 16:34:46
3   30      1000    10-MAR-2018 16:34:46
3   30      1400    11-MAR-2018 16:34:46
3   30      3000    12-MAR-2018 16:34:46
3   30      (null)  13-MAR-2018 16:34:46
4   40      4000    14-MAR-2018 16:34:46
4   40      5000    15-MAR-2018 16:34:46
4   40      (null)  16-MAR-2018 16:34:46
```

View on this table:

```
create view gview as
select id, sal, (Case when sal >= 5000 Then 'High Paid'                  
                      when Sal < 5000 Then 'Low Paid' End) As Status, 
       dates
from gr
```

Following works perfectly when I'm trying to get min Sal for each id.

```
select g1.Id, Min(g1.Sal), g1.Status 
from gview g1 join gview g2 on g1.id=g2.id   
where g1.Sal < g2.Sal
group by g1.Id, g1.Status
```

Output:

```
ID  MIN(G1.SAL) STATUS
1   1000        Low Paid
3   1000        Low Paid
2   2000        Low Paid
4   4000        Low Paid
```

Whereas, when I'm trying to get min dates for each id, it's not giving me any results.

```
select g1.Id, g1.Sal, g1.Status, min(g1.dates)
from gview g1 join gview g2 on g1.id=g2.id   
where g1.dates < g2.dates
group by g1.Id, g1.Sal, g1.Status

select g1.Id, g1.Sal, g1.Status, min(g1.dates)
from gview g1 join gview g2 on g1.id=g2.id   
where to_char(g1.dates, 'DD-MON-YYYY') < to_char(g1.dates, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
group by g1.Id, g1.Sal, g1.Status
```

So, just wondering is there anything I'm missing here ?

I need to get rows with the  minimum dates for each id. Expected results:

```
Id Sal  Status    min_date
-- ---- --------- ---------
 1 5000 High Paid 02-MAR-2018 16:34:46 
 2 2000 Low Paid  07-MAR-2018 16:34:46 
 3 1000 Low Paid  10-MAR-2018 16:34:46
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: `where g1.dates < g1.dates` ... how could this ever be true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have posted some expected results, so at least we can figure out what you're trying to do. You want to get the record in the view with the minimum date for the ID.

You want all the columns in the row so you cannot simply use a GROUP BY on `min(dates)`, as you have found out:

```
select g1.Id, g1.Sal, g1.Status, min(g1.dates)
from gview g1 join gview g2 on g1.id=g2.id   
where g1.dates < g2.dates
group by g1.Id, g1.Sal, g1.Status
```

This approach worked for your previous query because there was a relationship between `sal` and `status`. It doesn't work for you now because there is no relationship between `dates` and `sal` so your GROUP BY doesn't reduce to a single row.

There are various solutions to this class of problem. The clearest is to use a subquery to derive the minimum date and join that to your view:

```
select g1.*
from gview g1
     join ( select id, min(dates) as min_date
            from gr
            group by id ) g2
      on g1.id = g2.id
         and g1.dates = g2.min_date
order by g1.id;
```

[Here is a SQLFiddle demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/27105/1)

Comment: Sorry, I just made few corrections to post I did earlier.

Comment: So, I'm trying to get the records with min dates. Is that something I need to use multiple aggregate functions here. because I tried with following and it doesn't help.

select g1.Id, g1.Sal, g1.Status, min(g1.dates)
from gview g1 join gview g2 on g1.id=g2.id   
where g1.dates < g2.dates
group by g1.Id, g1.Status, g1.Sal

Expected results:

Id Sal   Status  min_date
1  5000 High Paid 02-MAR-2018 16:34:46
2  2000 Low Paid 07-MAR-2018 16:34:46
3 1000 Low Paid 10-MAR-2018 16:34:46

Comment: Expected results: 
Id Sal  Status   min_date 
1 5000  High Paid  02-MAR-2018 16:34:46 
2 2000  Low Paid  07-MAR-2018 16:34:46 
3 1000 Low Paid 10-MAR-2018 16:34:46

Comment: thank you very much, this works perfectly on my dummy data.

    
     select g1.*
    from gview g1
         join ( select id, min(dates) as min_date
                  from gr
                  group by id ) g2
         on g1.id = g2.id
              and g1.dates = g2.min_date
    order by g1.id;


However, I get duplicates on my prod data so I have to use distinct(id) . Any guesses on that ?

Comment: No. You need to figure out how your Production data differs from your sample data. Perhaps doing that exercise will lead you to knowing how to fix your query. But if not you need to revise your sample data set so it demonstrates the new problem, and post that set here.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to get min dates for each id

Why are you over-complicating things?

```
select id, min(dates)
from gr
group by id
```

is all you need.

Comment: Actually, you have over-simplified things. The OP's attempted solutions include the **full projection of the view**.  You have discounted that requirement. So this answer fails to give the Seeker the solution they need.

Answer (score 0):

Any of these should help you:

select ID,min(date) from gr group by id;

select ID, dates from gr where date in (select min(date) from gr);

You have no dates column in your view so you can't get that from the view.